# ggplot2 element_text(face = "italic")

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Problem

The text in my plot is not italic when I use `element_text(face = "italic")`.

**Plot 2** works correctly on my Macbook with ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 and R 3.4.2

**Plot 2** does not work on my Linux server with ggplot2_2.2.1 and R 3.4.0

### Solution

What steps should I take to setup fonts correctly for R?

### Example

Define a plot:

```
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1, y = 1), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "My Title")
```

Let's make the font red, just to be sure that we're changing the right element.

#### Plot 1 (bad)

This does not work as expected (the font is not italic):

```
p + theme(plot.title = element_text(color = "red", face = "italic"))
```

[image]

#### Plot 2 (good)

The problem goes away with `family = "sans"`:

```
p + theme(
  plot.title = element_text(
    color = "red", face = "italic", family = "sans"
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: R plots to devices. You need to look at the fonts being used by the device. On a Mac look at help page for the screen device: `?quartz`, while on Linux look at  `?x11`. Each of those pages has information (or links to other help pages) on choosing fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04, this was sufficient to get italic fonts working:

```
# Update the list of packages
sudo apt-get update

# Arial
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

# Helvetica
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended

# Refresh the font cache
sudo fc-cache -f -v

# Restart the R Shiny server
sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to get the italic font in the subtitle there is the `family = "sans"` argument in `plot.title()`.

```
theme (plot.title=element_text(
         lineheight= 0.9,
         color="black",
         face="plain",
         family="sans",
         size=18,
         hjust=0.0),
      plot.subtitle=element_text(
         lineheight=0.9,
         color="black",
         face="italic",
         size=16,
         hjust=0.0)
)
```